# Grails - No signature of method is applicable for argument types

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm starting with Grails (using mainly the Eclipse plugin) and have been having trouble with Grails reading Java src files - whether it's a jar in the bin folder, or a Java file in the src/java folder.

I've created an example of how I call from my controller, a Java static method, and for some reason there is a problem with the argument type. Here's the controller:

```
def attempt = {
    int counter = 20
    int val1 = 1
    int val2 = 1
    def list = Replicate.create(counter, val1, val2)
    render list.size()
}
```

And here is the Java file in the src/Java folder:

```
public class Replicate {

public static LinkedList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> create (int count, int val1, int val2){

    LinkedList<Pair<Integer, Integer>> list = new LinkedList<Pair<Integer,Integer>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        list.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(val1, val2));
    }

    return list;
}
}
```

When I try and load the page for the Controller's method, I get:

```
URI:
/clive-toolbox/cliveServices/attempt
Class:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message:
No signature of method: static tst.Replicate.create() is applicable for argument types:     (java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) values: [20, 1, 1] Possible solutions:     grep(), iterator()
```

The line that is highlighted as the error is this (in the controller):

```
def list = Replicate.create(counter, val1, val2)
```

And in other cases, working the same way, Grails manages to compile the project but just doesn't execute the method. I assume I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 3):

Your exception correctly states that the method Replicate.create() is not available to the controller.
Check the following,

```
1. You have imported the class right.
2. Package name is correct.
3. You have cleaned your application.
```

Try all the three mentioned above, it might help if the method is working on other places.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when trying to call a service method from a controller.

What I did wrong was that I had not typed: "servicename" at the top of the method in the controller where I called the service from.